# Passing the correct type parameter to MethodInfo GetMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

I know I could use a technique like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551532/how-to-get-the-correct-methodinfo-object-when-a-class-uses-generics-and-generic) to get my method.

E.g

```
MethodInfo firstMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(m => m.Name == "FirstOrDefault" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1)
```

I want to shortcut that process though.

I'm looking for [Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

I've tried both

```
// I'm just using string just as an example.
var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
MethodInfo firstMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
.GetMethod("FirstOrDefault", new Type[] { enumerableType });
```

and

```
MethodInfo firstMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
.GetMethod("FirstOrDefault", Type.EmptyTypes);
```

But both return `null`.

What would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunutely there is no easy way to get the correct overload when the parameter type is generic. You can do it using `LINQ` manually:

```
typeof(Enumerable)
  .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
  .First(x => x.Name == "FirstOrDefault" &&
              x.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
              x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
```

In this case since the `FirstOrDefault` has only one overload that takes one parameter you can remove the last condition.But it is necessary when there are overloads that takes same number of parameters of different types.

Comment: Ah, I see I missed a check there. Nice!

Comment: Calling `GetParameters` twice is not a good idea because it copies an internal array which used to cache parameters.

Comment: I can solve that with an anonymous function though. Thanks for pointing it out.